# echo radiobutton value from mysql table

Tags: php

How can i loop all questions in a row to display as radio button answers?

I have 4 tables in $row that i want to print as radio button survey.

```
Question nr1   (Radiobutton)Answer0   (Radiobutton)ansewer1   (Radiobutton)answer2
Question nr2   (Radiobutton)Answer0   (Radiobutton)ansewer1   (Radiobutton)answer2
Question nr3   (Radiobutton)Answer0   (Radiobutton)ansewer1   (Radiobutton)answer2
```

and so on.....

```
 <?php

 $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM que");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['que_id'] . " " . $row['que_question'] . " " . $row['que_answer0'] . " " . $row['que_answer1'] . " " . $row['que_answer2']  ;
 echo "<br>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Instead of `(Radiobutton)` you put `<input type="radio"/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM que");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['que_id'] . " " . $row['que_question'] . " " . $row['que_answer0'] . " " . $row['que_answer1'] . " " . $row['que_answer2']  ;
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

to this:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM que");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo '' . $row['que_question'] . '<br>
<input type="radio" name="' . $row['que_id'] . '" value="male">' . $row['que_answer0'] . '<br>
<input type="radio" name="' . $row['que_id'] . '" value="male">' . $row['que_answer1'] . '<br>
<input type="radio" name="' . $row['que_id'] . '" value="male">' . $row['que_answer0'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: If i put different values in the form, how can i users prevent from choosing all 3 answers?

Comment: @user3906056 only 1 radio button can be selected. Multiple options can only be selected in a `<select>` menu or if you are using checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM que");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{            

    echo $row['que_question'].' ';
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question[".$row['que_id']."]' value='".$row['que_answer1']."'">." ";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question[".$row['que_id']."]' value='".$row['que_answer2']."'">." ";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question[".$row['que_id']."]' value='".$row['que_answer3']."'">."<br>";

  }
```